# Console apps execution in serial

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to chain 'n' number of executables, with the output of the 'n-1'th exe being passed as the input of 'n'th exe. I plan to use XML file to configure the executable position, path, i/p, o/p etc.

My question is how to link 'n-1' to 'n' when there are multiple outputs and multiple inputs(command line params).
I've some ideas about it, but would like to see what others think, maybe I'll come to know about an efficient/quick way to do this. A design pattern for flexible xml configs would help.

pseudo XML structure that I would be using

```
<executables>
  <entity position="1" exePath="c:\something1.exe">
     <op><name="a" value=""></op>
  </entity>
  <entity position="2" exePath="c:\something2.exe">
   <ip><name="a"></ip>
   <op><name="b"  value=""></op>
  </entity>
  <entity position="3" exePath="c:\something3.exe">
   <ip><name="b"</ip>
  </entity>
</executables>
```

I would have knowledge about the i/p and o/p before I configure these. The context is I might or might not include certain nodes in some of the types of chaining I'll use, effectively making a flexible serial exe execution path.

Comment: What about the existing pipe command? [Using command redirection operators](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), although the above is for XP it works across Windows, to the best of my knowledge, and most flavors of *nix as well [Intro to Unix: Pipes and Filters](http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/pipesfilters.html)...

Comment: Or something more fancy... are you already aware of [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)?

Comment: Want to keep it at console level, don't want to go into MSMQ any other IPC.

Comment: How big is the output of each executable? If it's small enough, you could use temp files between them.

Comment: It would be small. Flags and directories names and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Process class for that. The following code should do the trick for two executables:

```
using (Process outerProc = new Process())
{
    outerProc.StartInfo.FileName = "something1.exe";
    outerProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    outerProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    outerProc.Start();

    string str = outerProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    using(Process innerProc = new Process())
    {
        innerProc.StartInfo.FileName = "something2.exe";
        innerProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        innerProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        innerProc.Start();

        innerProc.StandardInput.Write(str);
        innerProc.WaitForExit();
    }

    outerProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

You can easily modify it to fit your "n-1" to "n" case.

Comment: It would be a loop on entity nodes inside the executable node. Sorry for not inserting the c# code in the question. Actually question is about transferring i/p and o/p between the processes.

Comment: Hum, I thought you were talking about StandardInput and StandardOutput, but you can set a Process arguments through its [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx). Regarding "output parameters" I don't know what you mean by that...